# Grpd as a locally presentable category

Tags: category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

Is the category of groupoids **Grpd** a locally presentable category? If the answer is yes, can someone sketch a proof or point a reference out?

Thanks

Comment: The category of *small* groupoids is sketchable, right?

Comment: The easiest way is to observe that it's an accessibly embedded reflective subcategory of $\mathbf{sSet}$, which is locally finitely presentable.

Comment: @ZhenLin for a reflective subcategory you need a full subcategory and an inclusion functor, however for Grpd and sSet you have the nerve functor to mediate between Grpd and sSet, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but the nerve functor is a fully faithful (indeed, injective on objects) accessible functor that has a left adjoint, so it is equivalent (indeed, isomorphic) to such a functor.